# Irreducible polynomials and irreducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need some help with an exercise (proved half of it but now I'm stuck on the other half). This is an exercise from Smith's book about algebraic geometry:

Show that a hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$ is irreducible if and only if the defining equation $F$ is a power of an irreducible polynomial $G$.

Here is what I have so far:

Proof: $\implies$: Let $V(F)$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$. Assume $F$ is not a power of an irreducible polynomial. Then $F$ can be factored as $F = GH$ for some non-constant polynomials $G,H$. But then $V(F) = V(G)\cup V(H)$ is a union of two non-empty proper subvarieties hence reducible.

> Is this correct so far?

And this is the part that I'm stuck with:

$\Longleftarrow$: Now assume $F=G^n$ where $G$ is irreducible. Then $V(F) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n V(G) = V(G)$.

I want to say something like "Then $V(G)$ does not contain two non-empty proper subvarieties because $G$ is irreducible" but it's not so clear to me how to prove this.

> Please could someone help me finish this proof?

**Note/Edit**

This exercise is on page 12 and so far we only have the definition of variety, subvariety, morphism and dimension. Ideals and radicals have not been mentioned.

Comment: First part: You should note there that $G\neq H$. Couln't it be that $V(G) = V(H)$ or that one of both is contained in the other?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp You're right. But I think these cases are excluded because $F$ is not a power of an irreducible polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

This works without the notion of ideals. Affine varieties are considered to be the common zero set of a collection of polynomials.

Let $G$ be an irreducible polynomial. Let $$V(G)=V(F_i, i \in I) \cup V(H_j, j \in J) = V(F_iH_j, i \in I, j \in J)$$
be the union of two closed subsets. We have to show, that one of those is not proper.

Fix $i \in I$ and assume $G \not\mid F_i$. We have $V(G) \subset V(F_iH_j)$ for all $j \in J$, hence  by [Study's Lemma](http://math.ucr.edu/~ziv/papers/137-4.pdf) (**), we obtain $G|F_iH_j$. $G$ is irreducible, the polynomial ring is factorial, thus we get $G|H_j$ for any $j$. This shows that we can assume $G|F_i$ for any $i$ (If not, we have $G|H_j$ for any $j$). This yields 
$$V(G) \subset \bigcap_i V(F_i) = V(F_i, i \in I),$$
thus we have shown that $V(G)$ is irreducible, since it is not the union of two proper closed subsets.

---

(**) I assume the field to be algebraically closed, since the statement is wrong without that assumption anway, as the irreducible one-point set $V(x(x^2+1)) \subset \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb R}$ shows. As far as I can remember, your book does only treat the complex case, at least in the first chapter.

Comment: Study's Lemma seems like a bit of an overly powerful tool to use here, especially given the book in question was written to be approachable by people with little to no algebraic background. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can show that a closed set $X$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is irreducible if and only if the ideal $I(X)$ corresonding to $X$ is a prime ideal in $k[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  When does a single element $G \in k[X_1, ... , X_n]$ generate a prime ideal?

Comment: I'm sorry but ideals have not been mentioned in the book so far. This exercise is on page 12 and so far there have only been given the definition of a variety, a morphism and the dimension. So I should be able to find a proof using those I suppose.

Comment: Question: is the field you're working with algebraically closed?

Comment: Yes, it is. The book assumes that $\mathbb A = \mathbb C$. Does it make this exercise easier?